# How to put the div tags on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to know that, how to put the div tag generated with ajax dynamically onto the canvas.

I just create the div tag with ajax and append the generated divs to the another div tag on the jsp page. and i want to add main div on the canvas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`canvas` is an HTML element which can be used to draw graphics using scripting (usually JavaScript), so It's impossible to add an element inside canvas element, but you can play with css `position` to move the div inside canvas

```
<div class="container">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container{postion: relative;}
#myCanvas{background: red;}
#myDiv{height: 50px;width: 50px;background: blue;
position: absolute; top:10px;
}
```

see [JSFIDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a2ofwyym/)

Comment: Thanks for your replay and your time.

Comment: did my anwser useful to you ?

Comment: opppppss, no.i want to put the div tag into canvs.

Answer (score 5):

You can't just render HTML into a canvas. Instead, one approach would be to use an SVG image containing the content you want to render.

To draw HTML content, you'd use a `<foreignObject>` element containing the HTML, then draw that SVG image into your canvas.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">' +
  '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
  '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:40px">' +
  '<em>I</em> like ' +
  '<span style="color:white; text-shadow:0 0 2px blue;">' +
  'cheese</span>' +
  '</div>' +
  '</foreignObject>' +
  '</svg>';

var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {
  type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

img.src = url;
```

You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas).

---

### Limitations

This approach has a lot of limitations :

- IE below Edge just doesn't support `<foreignObject>`, so this won't work at all **+** it will taint the canvas, *even if the result is a blank rect*, since these browser do so as soon as any svg images as been drawn on it, for security reasons.
- Some browsers (at least Safari 9) do taint the canvas when a `<foreignObject>` is drawn on it, for security reasons.
- Some elements do render weirdly (`<button>` doesn't have any style in FF, `<video>` is just a weird thing on some UA ...).
- No external resource will be loaded into the `<img>` element, images will have to be converted to dataURL first, styles will have to be appended directly into the svg, or inline in the HTML tags, fonts will have to be dataURL encoded.

So the best approach, if you don't mind using a library, is still to use [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/).

If you do mind using a library, then you can try to do what it does :
use the native canvas drawing methods to **draw** each of the HTML elements and its styles.

Comment: Interesting approach!

Comment: thanks for ur answer but it may actually convert into image right.?

Comment: @Jatin_g: Yes, it does.

Comment: i don't want to create div to image bcz i draw the line between generated div with jsPlumb and i applied some hover and click event on the line, and now i convert it into image then how could event work.?

Comment: it won't, you can't have html drawn on a canvas and still keep it behaving as html. if you just want to have a bit of html displayed on top of a canvas element @T.J.Crowder 's solution is the way to go.

Comment: if you have some example of some link as per my requirement, share it here. i got some idea as per your review. thanks for your golden time for me. thanks again.

Comment: it would probably better for you to share what you've got so far. :)

Comment: **Important note to add :** Some browsers (at least Safari 9) do taint the canvas when a `<foreignObject>` is contained in the drawn svg. Any stylesheets must be included in the svg before the conversion to dataURL. Some elements will render weirdly (i.e `<button>` or `<video>`). The best approach is still to **draw** it. Not directly, but by actually using the canvas drawing methods, just like [html2canvas.js](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) does.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks for the heads up. Could you make an edit to the response? :)

Comment: @toskv just done the edit, please review it, you may not approve it... Also, I will write to MDN guys since this article shouldn't be here, this is more of a hack than a real solution for the problem.

Answer (score 2):

A canvas can't actually *contain* a `div` (or any other HTML tag), it's a drawing surface you can draw on.

But you can position the div *on top of* the canvas in the z-order, e.g.:

```js
// Lower
var ctx = document.getElementById("lower-canvas").getContext('2d');
var path = new Path2D();
path.arc(100, 100, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fillStyle = ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
ctx.fill(path);

// Upper
ctx = document.getElementById("upper-canvas").getContext('2d');
path = new Path2D();
path.arc(75, 75, 50, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fillStyle = ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
ctx.fill(path);
```

```css
#lower-canvas, #upper-canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}
#upper-canvas {
  z-index: 2;
}
#the-div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="lower-canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<canvas id="upper-canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<div id="the-div">This is the div</div>
```

In that example, we don't even need `z-index` because the div is absolutely positioned but the canvas isn't, and by default positioned elements are on a layer "nearer" the viewer than non-positioned elements. If you are positioning the canvas, you'd add something like `z-index: 10` (using whatever value was appropriate) to ensure the div was "nearer" the viewer in the order for the positioned layer.

Comment: here, you draw arc on canvas. but if we want to put above div on canvas.?

Comment: @Jatin_g: Then it gets ugly, you'd need separate canvases for the bits you wanted over the div and the bits you wanted under it.

Comment: but i have some other requirements,need to do as per i have mentioned.

Comment: @Jatin_g: Then you'll need at least two canvases. Which is fine, we use multiple elements all the time, really, don't we? :-)

Comment: can i replace the div  with canvas.?

Comment: @Jatin_g: No. frankly, it sounds like you should be using SVG, not a canvas. SVG elements are *elements*, and you can hook events on them. You might also look at Raphael.js.

Comment: but when i zoom out the page, arrow position get change on other side to page.and arrow moved. so i just think that i have to put the divs on canvas.