# Is there a way to combine a table and canvas into a single image?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

**Context**

- I have created one page using `HTML` and `JavaScript`.
- The page contains a table and a canvas which is used to draw images based on `JavaScript` code.
- I know how to convert the canvas -element to image (by using toDataURL()).

**Question**

I need to combine the HTML table also with the canvas and produce it as a single image. Is there a way to do so?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html moznomarginboxes mozdisallowselectionprint>
<head>

<script>

function byId(id,parent){return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementById(id);}
 window.addEventListener('load', onLoadd, false);

 function onLoadd(evt)
{
drawBkg(byId('canvas'), 3.78, "0.35", "green");
}

function drawBkg(canvasElem, squareSize, minorLineWidthStr, lineColStr)
{
var nLinesDone = 0;
var i, curX, curY;
var ctx = canvasElem.getContext('2d');
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasElem.width,canvasElem.height);

// draw the vertical lines
curX=0;
ctx.strokeStyle = lineColStr;
while (curX < canvasElem.width)
{

    if (nLinesDone % 5 == 0)
        ctx.lineWidth = 0.69;
    else
        ctx.lineWidth = minorLineWidthStr;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(curX, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(curX, canvasElem.height);
    ctx.stroke();

    curX += squareSize;
    nLinesDone++;
}

// draw the horizontal lines
curY=0;
nLinesDone = 0;
while (curY < canvasElem.height)
{
    if (nLinesDone % 5 == 0)
        ctx.lineWidth = 0.69;
    else
        ctx.lineWidth = minorLineWidthStr;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, curY);
    ctx.lineTo(canvasElem.width, curY);
    ctx.stroke();

    curY += squareSize;
    nLinesDone++;
}
}



function print_voucher(){
var win=window.open();

win.document.write("<br><img style='margin:0' src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"'/>");
win.print();
win.location.reload();
}
</script>
 </head>
<body>

<div id='txt'></div>
<table style="width:600">
<tr>
    <td>Patient ID:</td>
    <td>1234</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Patient Name:</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Patient Age:</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Patient Gender:</td>
        <td>Male</td>
    </tr>
</table> 
 <canvas id="canvas" width="1030" height="600"></canvas>
    <button onclick="onDocLoaded()">Click Me</button>
    <input type="button" id="test" value="Print" onClick="print_voucher();"> </input>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34565458/1169519

Comment: The problem with SVG `foreignObject` and Canvas is that some browsers do not let you export the Canvas then because the SVG *tainted* the Canvas. The cleanest approach I think it's unfortunately to draw the table in Canvas (from scratch or with some tool)

Comment: @student Please see the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/).

Code:

```
function print_voucher() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  html2canvas(container, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    },
    width: container.width,
    height: container.height
  });
}
```

Working fiddle: (Note that I append the generated canvas image to the body)

```js
function byId(id, parent) {
  return (parent == undefined ? document : parent).getElementById(id);
}
window.addEventListener('load', onLoadd, false);

function onLoadd(evt) {
  drawBkg(byId('canvas'), 3.78, "0.35", "green");
}

function drawBkg(canvasElem, squareSize, minorLineWidthStr, lineColStr) {
  var nLinesDone = 0;
  var i, curX, curY;
  var ctx = canvasElem.getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElem.width, canvasElem.height);

  // draw the vertical lines
  curX = 0;
  ctx.strokeStyle = lineColStr;
  while (curX < canvasElem.width) {

    if (nLinesDone % 5 == 0)
      ctx.lineWidth = 0.69;
    else
      ctx.lineWidth = minorLineWidthStr;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(curX, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(curX, canvasElem.height);
    ctx.stroke();

    curX += squareSize;
    nLinesDone++;
  }

  // draw the horizontal lines
  curY = 0;
  nLinesDone = 0;
  while (curY < canvasElem.height) {
    if (nLinesDone % 5 == 0)
      ctx.lineWidth = 0.69;
    else
      ctx.lineWidth = minorLineWidthStr;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, curY);
    ctx.lineTo(canvasElem.width, curY);
    ctx.stroke();

    curY += squareSize;
    nLinesDone++;
  }
}



function print_voucher() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  html2canvas(container, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    },
    width: container.width,
    height: container.height
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id='txt'></div>
  <div id="container">
    <table style="width:600">
      <tr>
        <td>Patient ID:</td>
        <td>1234</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Patient Name:</td>
        <td>Jackson</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Patient Age:</td>
        <td>94</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Patient Gender:</td>
        <td>Male</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1030" height="600"></canvas>
  </div>
  <button onclick="onDocLoaded()">Click Me</button>
  <input type="button" id="test" value="Print" onClick="print_voucher();"></input>
```

Comment: :grins: glad to see you've liberated my `byId` function. ;)

Comment: @Gilsha that code snippet is a little bit out of date : html2canvas does return promise since 0.5

Comment: @enhzflep could you explain the use of  `parent` in this function?

Comment: @Kaiido - I never bothered to benchmark it (hangs-head-in-shame) but the aim was to provide a mechanism by which the result could be more quickly evaluated. Think of a DOM tree that has 4 divs as children of the body. Now, imagine that each of these divs has 1000 children - if one knows which div is the top-level parent, ~ 3/4 of the tree may be immediately disregarded. I have similar helper functions for the other CSS querying funcs - getElementsByTagName, getElementsByClassName, querySelector, querySelectorAll etc - obviously, browser implementations may render my efforts entirely wasted. :)

Comment: @enhzflep my concern is more that `getElementById` is a `Document` method, not a `Node` one. Your use case example show me that my wonders were founded. Though, It would work for `getElementsByClassName`, `getElementsByTagName`, `querySelector` etc.

Comment: @Kaiido - thank-you for your thoughts. I can't believe I never tested it in order to prove that its useless! Memory vaguely suggests I used it for one of the others first and then updated all of my other helper funcs. Oh well, I've just improved my working knowledge and now have quite a handy means by which to fingerprint code that uses snippets of mine. :grins: - Thank-you very much. :)